# jquery slider doesn't continue after i get to the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am sure I am missing something simple and just need a new pair of eyes. The problem I am having is with continuing back to the first div with the class of 'slide' once i get to the last one., it should go back to the first element but its not.   I just need fresh eyes on this one I can't figure out what the problem is thanks in advance for any help.
Here is the function i created, I don't want to post all the html so I cam adding a codepen link.

```
 $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
   var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
   var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
   var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
   var nextDot = currentDot.next();

   if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
     nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
     nextDot = $('.dot').first();
   }
   currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
   nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
   currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
   nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
 });
```

Here is my codepen link:
http://codepen.io/cavascript/pen/GoQdoJ

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Good idea with adding a codepen link,  we don't usually see many new people who think to do that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have other element after the last slide. Just filter `nextSlide` with class `slide`. And same for the `nextDot`

```
var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.slide');
var nextDot = currentDot.next('.dot');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input that seemed like it would do the trick but it didnt :( I know i have to be missing something if you check out my link to my codepen you can see it in full